# ms Access import table from file in a query

Tags: sql, ms-access

Is there a way to have a msAccess DB query import a table from file?

Comment: Can you clarify? Do you want the table to be created from the file or have you already created the table and want to import data from the file? And do you want to do all this via VBA?

Comment: I already have the file and using a query i want to import the file into the database table

Comment: I can export the table into any format though I was leaning towards xml. Just to clarify some, I want to do this in a query since I plan to have a delphi application call the query.

Comment: The fact that you want to do this in Delphi should be part of the questions, or also a tag. The failure to specify the programming environment means people will assume you're programming in VBA in Access.

Comment: I have added a note on using a CSV file in a query.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, as long as the data is organized. You can use VBA or a macro with TransferText or you can use Get External Data from the menu or ribbon, which will guide you through the steps.

EDIT

You can import into a new or existing table from say, CSV, like so:

```
SELECT * INTO NewTable
FROM [Text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;Database=C:\Docs].Test.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution will vary depending on the format of the file. If it's simple enough, checking out the options on the **External Data** tab *(MS Access 2007)* in the **Import** section, may do the trick.

For complex integrations, I'll often use SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) to migrate the data into Access, where I can then process it with SQL queries. Of course, SSIS is a much "heavier" solution with a bit of a learning curve, but its been handy when the wizards aren't flexible enough.