# Importing a text with separators

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to automate the adding of new text files, which all have the same (known) layout.

The columns are separated using tabs (the TAB button). My question is, is it possible to do this in VBA? Like, in the access wizard for importing text files?

I am using the `DoCmd.TransferText` method in VBA

Comment: The easiest way to start with this sort of process is to record a macro of you doing it manually in excel/access or whatever, then take the generated VBA and generalize it for input params etc.

Comment: @JonEgerton I don't believe you can record macros in Access.

Comment: No, but you should be able to do so in Excel, and then re-use the generated VB into your code - the object model will be available (as long as you pull in the right references).

Comment: @JonEgerton Unless you were opening up an Access table via Excel VBA then you would not have access to a table.  Also why would you want to write it in Excel and use an Excel reference in Access when it could be done natively in Access? I understand trying to simplify by recording a macro but in this instance would likely further confuse the issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll need to go through the wizard once to make your specification file. TO do this import your text file like normal but before you get too deep into the wizard click on the bottom left, the "Advanced..." button. This is where you make your spec file.

[image]

Make ll these columns match your input file, data types and all. Be sure to select the `{tab}` field delimiter and the appropriate text qualifier if you are using one.

[image]

Save your spec (which can later be edited by coming back to this same screen and clicking `Specs...` then saving over your old one)

Now you can use in VBA like this

```
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "your spec name", "destination table name", sourceFilePath
```

There is a parameter `HasFieldNames` that you'll have to decide if it is `true` or `false` based on your file.

Comment: Technically you can also assemble your own I/O specs from XML using the newer import/export profile API. It's tricky but possible--I've done it myself before. See [ImportExportSpecification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff820988.aspx), [The New Import/Export Specification OM](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thirdoffive/archive/2006/10/12/the-new-import-export-specification-om.aspx), [The New Import/Export Specifications UI](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thirdoffive/archive/2006/10/17/the-new-import-export-specifications-ui.aspx)

Comment: @JoshuaHonig What is the advantage to making it yourself? Is the mapping any "better" than this method? This is a pretty quick process, no?

Comment: You can create specs on the fly at runtime. Sometimes that's necessary, especially if an application is distributed to other people.

Comment: I have tried this with the following code:

`DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "Tags_AI_DB_Importspecificatie", "Tags_AI_DB", "C:\Data\PLC_MOBZ\Test\Scada_DBs\Tags_AI_DB.txt", True`

(The "True" for using the first row as field names, but for some reason, this makes access just delete the first row and instead call the columns "row1, row2, row3, row4 etc"

Answer (score 3):

With the import wizard the downside is that for even the slightest change in file format, you'll have to click through all those steps *yet again* to get the import working.

Check out @Remou's answer in [ms Access import table from file in a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660377/ms-access-import-table-from-file-in-a-query) for a way to do it in straight SQL. I am actually using the same method in a project of mine. I use something like this (see my link for the details):

```
insert into MyTable (column-list...)
select (column-list...)
from [data-source-specifications].[file-name]
any-other-clauses...;
```

Just one caveat. If you put this SQL syntax into a normal Access query object, there's a good chance that Access will mangle it to the point where it won't even be able to open the query object. So compose and save the query in a text file while you try it out in Access. Once the query is tested and working, save it in a VBA subroutine so that Access will run it exactly as is, like so:

```
sub MyTableImport()
  sqlStr = "         insert into MyTable (column-list) " ' leave a space at the
  sqlStr = sqlStr & "select (column-list...) " ' end of each line of the string
  sqlStr = sqlStr & "from [data-source-specifications].[file-name] "
  sqlStr = sqlStr & "any-other-clauses... ;"

  DoCmd.RunSQL sqlStr
end sub
```