# MS Access Convert from Unicode when Reading from Text File

Tags: unicode, ms-access-2013

So, I have an Access database where I import data from a text file.  The file is semi-colon delimited.  Occasionally (and will become more frequent) I receive a file from one of our affiliates from Russia.  The file has unicode (I think) characters like "Ìèðîøíèêîâ" instead of "Мирошников".  Ultimately, I'd like to translate those into English upon import, but for now, I'll accept the Russian characters.

How should I go about doing this?  Currently, I'm reading each line of the file, using the SPLIT function to separate each field by the ";" separator into an array, and sticking each array element into a table.  Would changing the system Keyboard Layout to Russian prior to this work, or is it more complicated than that.

Does any of this make sense, or should I just bag it and go grab a beer (or some Vodka)?

Thanks!

Comment: FilesystemObject might help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/314cz14s(v=vs.84).aspx, the export format may be a problem. Vodka? Which programming language? :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create an "Import Specification" that will tell Access how to convert the character data. Follow the procedure here...

[Importing a text with separators using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15067136/2144390)

...and choose the appropriate character set from the "Code Page" combo box.

If you need to perform the imports from VBA code then you can save the specification (using the "Save As..." button) and then re-use that specification in a `DoCmd.TransferText` statement.